# "Did the glass get broken"

Tags: past-tense, interrogatives, causative-get

I know if I say "The glass got broken" It is usually a passive construction and it could mean "The glass was broken" / as in an action instead of a state or it could mean "The glass has been broken", and it could also mean "The glass became broken".

But my question is if I use "an interrogative' with "Get" as in "Did the glass get broken".

Would the use of "did with get" also depicts three senses as in "was", "has been" and "became"?

Comment: I've changed to "the glass" to match the title, and because you seem to be talking about a glass (cup) not the substance "glass".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "Did the glass get broken?" is equivalent in the same way as you outlined to "Was the glass broken?", "Has the glass been broken?", and "Did the glass become broken?".